# Inserting rows into oracle with PL/SQL reading from XML CLOB

Tags: xml, plsql

I am having some real problems with PL/SQL.

I have written a stored procedure which ready a record from an XML and inserts this into a database table.

This compiles cleanly for single record input. But I am looking for the way to insert all the records of a large XML file and can't figure out how to make the look function correctly.

Here is the code that is working for single record input:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE PROCEDURE "DORTO"."DORTOSALES" (P_DE_SALES CLOB)
AS
I_ORTP VARCHAR2 (6);
I_ORNO VARCHAR2 (20);
I_IVNO NUMBER (9);
I_CUNO VARCHAR2 (20);
I_YREF VARCHAR2 (60);
I_OREF VARCHAR2 (60);
I_CUOR VARCHAR2 (40);
I_ITCL VARCHAR2 (10);
I_ITNO VARCHAR2 (30);
I_IVQT NUMBER (15);
I_BANO VARCHAR2 (40);
I_IVDT NUMBER (8);
I_DLIX NUMBER (11);
I_ELNO VARCHAR2 (16);
I_PONR NUMBER (5);
I_CNNO VARCHAR2 (20);
I_CNIV NUMBER (9);
I_TRANSFER TIMESTAMP(6);
BEGIN

  -- FOR i IN (

   SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(P_DE_SALES), '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/orderType')
  ,EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(P_DE_SALES), '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/orderNumber')
  ,EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(P_DE_SALES), '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/customerNumber')
  ,EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(P_DE_SALES), '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/customerOrderReference')
  ,EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(P_DE_SALES), '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/batchNumber')
  ,EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(P_DE_SALES), '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/deliveryNoteNumber')
  ,EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(P_DE_SALES), '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/elementNumber')
  ,EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(P_DE_SALES), '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/orderLineNumber')
  ,EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(P_DE_SALES), '/dortoSalesInputIF/creditNote/creditNoteOrderNumber')
  ,EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(P_DE_SALES), '/dortoSalesInputIF/creditNote/orderNumberCreditNote')
  ,EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(P_DE_SALES), '/dortoSalesInputIF/creditNote/creditNoteNumber')
  ,EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(P_DE_SALES), '/dortoSalesInputIF/creditNote/creditNoteInvoiceNumber')
  ,EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(P_DE_SALES), '/dortoSalesInputIF/invoice/invoiceNumber')
  ,EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(P_DE_SALES), '/dortoSalesInputIF/invoice/itemClassification')
  ,EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(P_DE_SALES), '/dortoSalesInputIF/invoice/itemMaterialNumber')
  ,EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(P_DE_SALES), '/dortoSalesInputIF/invoice/invoicedQuantity')
  ,EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(P_DE_SALES), '/dortoSalesInputIF/invoice/invoiceDate')
 INTO I_ORTP,I_ORNO,I_CUNO,I_CUOR,I_BANO,I_DLIX,I_ELNO,I_PONR,I_YREF,I_OREF,I_CNNO,I_CNIV,I_IVNO,I_ITCL,I_ITNO,I_IVQT,I_IVDT
 FROM TABLE(XMLSequence(xmltype(P_DE_SALES))) x ; --LOOP
 INSERT INTO DE_SALES (ORTP,ORNO,CUNO,CUOR,BANO,DLIX,ELNO,PONR,YREF,OREF,CNNO,CNIV,IVNO,ITCL,ITNO,IVQT,IVDT,TRANSFER) VALUES
 --(i.I_ORTP,i.I_ORNO,i.I_CUNO,i.I_CUOR,i.I_BANO,i.I_DLIX,i.I_ELNO,i.I_PONR,i.I_YREF,i.I_OREF,i.I_CNNO,i.I_CNIV,i.I_IVNO,i.I_ITCL,i.I_ITNO,i.I_IVQT,i.I_IVDT,sysdate);

 (I_ORTP,I_ORNO,I_CUNO,I_CUOR,I_BANO,I_DLIX,I_ELNO,I_PONR,I_YREF,I_OREF,I_CNNO,I_CNIV,I_IVNO,I_ITCL,I_ITNO,I_IVQT,I_IVDT,sysdate);

 --END LOOP;

 COMMIT;
END;
```

You can see that I commented out my failed attempt at looping. Can somebody help me out here why my looping through the XML to then do the insert isn't working?

Thanks,

Tom

---

Update - here is a sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<dortoSalesInputIF>
    <order>
        <orderType>DO1</orderType>
        <orderNumber>1304315</orderNumber>
        <customerNumber>5104081</customerNumber>
        <customerOrderReference></customerOrderReference>
        <batchNumber></batchNumber>
        <deliveryNoteNumber>8337697</deliveryNoteNumber>
        <elementNumber></elementNumber>
        <orderLineNumber>2</orderLineNumber>
    </order>
    <creditNote>
        <creditNoteOrderNumber>617</creditNoteOrderNumber>
        <orderNumberCreditNote>59237</orderNumberCreditNote>
        <creditNoteNumber></creditNoteNumber>
        <creditNoteInvoiceNumber></creditNoteInvoiceNumber>
    </creditNote>
    <invoice>
        <invoiceNumber>31615915</invoiceNumber>
        <itemClassification>TRA</itemClassification>
        <itemMaterialNumber>100000101</itemMaterialNumber>
        <invoicedQuantity>1</invoicedQuantity>
        <invoiceDate>20160531</invoiceDate>
    </invoice>
</dortoSalesInputIF>
<dortoSalesInputIF>
    <order>
        <orderType>DO1</orderType>
        <orderNumber>1304316</orderNumber>
        <customerNumber>5104082</customerNumber>
        <customerOrderReference></customerOrderReference>
        <batchNumber></batchNumber>
        <deliveryNoteNumber>8337698</deliveryNoteNumber>
        <elementNumber></elementNumber>
        <orderLineNumber>2</orderLineNumber>
    </order>
    <creditNote>
        <creditNoteOrderNumber>618</creditNoteOrderNumber>
        <orderNumberCreditNote>59238</orderNumberCreditNote>
        <creditNoteNumber></creditNoteNumber>
        <creditNoteInvoiceNumber></creditNoteInvoiceNumber>
    </creditNote>
    <invoice>
        <invoiceNumber>31615916</invoiceNumber>
        <itemClassification>TRA</itemClassification>
        <itemMaterialNumber>100000101</itemMaterialNumber>
        <invoicedQuantity>1</invoicedQuantity>
        <invoiceDate>20160531</invoiceDate>
    </invoice>
</dortoSalesInputIF>
```

UPDATE:

I have tried the following - greatly simplifying the XML structure - including two reocrds to be inserted in the database.

The single insert (with only record in the XML) works just fine, but it is the insert where I have two that is failing.

I am getting the following error:

ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence

ORA-06512: at line 67

ORA-06512: at line 67

ORA-06512: at line 121

```
declare
  l_xml      xmltype := xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<dortoSalesInputIF>
    <order>
        <orderType>DO1</orderType>
        <orderNumber>1304315</orderNumber>
        <customerNumber>5104081</customerNumber>
        <customerOrderReference></customerOrderReference>
        <batchNumber></batchNumber>
        <deliveryNoteNumber>8337697</deliveryNoteNumber>
        <elementNumber></elementNumber>
        <orderLineNumber>2</orderLineNumber>
        <creditNoteOrderNumber>617</creditNoteOrderNumber>
        <orderNumberCreditNote>59237</orderNumberCreditNote>
        <creditNoteNumber></creditNoteNumber>
        <creditNoteInvoiceNumber></creditNoteInvoiceNumber>
        <invoiceNumber>31615915</invoiceNumber>
        <itemClassification>TRA</itemClassification>
        <itemMaterialNumber>100000101</itemMaterialNumber>
        <invoicedQuantity>1</invoicedQuantity>
        <invoiceDate>20160531</invoiceDate>
    </order>
    <order>
        <orderType>DO1</orderType>
        <orderNumber>1304316</orderNumber>
        <customerNumber>5104082</customerNumber>
        <customerOrderReference></customerOrderReference>
        <batchNumber></batchNumber>
        <deliveryNoteNumber>8337698</deliveryNoteNumber>
        <elementNumber></elementNumber>
        <orderLineNumber>2</orderLineNumber>
        <creditNoteOrderNumber>618</creditNoteOrderNumber>
        <orderNumberCreditNote>59238</orderNumberCreditNote>
        <creditNoteNumber></creditNoteNumber>
        <creditNoteInvoiceNumber></creditNoteInvoiceNumber>
        <invoiceNumber>31615916</invoiceNumber>
        <itemClassification>TRA</itemClassification>
        <itemMaterialNumber>100000101</itemMaterialNumber>
        <invoicedQuantity>1</invoicedQuantity>
        <invoiceDate>20160531</invoiceDate>
    </order>
</dortoSalesInputIF>');

procedure DORTOSALES (i_clob in xmltype)
AS
  I_ORTP     varchar2(6);
  I_ORNO     varchar2(20);
  I_IVNO     number(9);
  I_CUNO     varchar2(20);
  I_YREF     varchar2(60);
  I_OREF     varchar2(60);
  I_CUOR     varchar2(40);
  I_ITCL     varchar2(10);
  I_ITNO     varchar2(30);
  I_IVQT     number(15);
  I_BANO     varchar2(40);
  I_IVDT     number(8);
  I_DLIX     number(11);
  I_ELNO     varchar2(16);
  I_PONR     number(5);
  I_CNNO     varchar2(20);
  I_CNIV     number(9);
  I_TRANSFER timestamp(6);

begin

  for i in  
  (
    SELECT  xt.*
    FROM    XMLTABLE ('/dortoSalesInputIF'
            PASSING  l_xml
            COLUMNS
              orderType               PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/orderType',
              orderNumber             PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/orderNumber',
              customerNumber          PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/customerNumber',
              customerOrderReference  PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/customerOrderReference',
              batchNumber             PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/batchNumber',
              deliveryNoteNumber      PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/deliveryNoteNumber',
              elementNumber           PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/elementNumber',
              orderLineNumber         PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/orderLineNumber',
              creditNoteOrderNumber   PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/creditNoteOrderNumber',
              orderNumberCreditNote   PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/orderNumberCreditNote',
              creditNoteNumber        PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/creditNoteNumber',
              creditNoteInvoiceNumber PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/creditNoteInvoiceNumber',
              invoiceNumber           PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/invoiceNumber',
              itemClassification      PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/itemClassification',
              itemMaterialNumber      PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/itemMaterialNumber',
              invoicedQuantity        PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/invoicedQuantity',
              invoiceDate             PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/invoiceDate'
            ) xt
  )
  loop
    INSERT INTO DE_SALES (ORTP,ORNO,CUNO,CUOR,BANO,DLIX,ELNO,PONR,YREF,OREF,CNNO,CNIV,IVNO,ITCL,ITNO,IVQT,IVDT,TRANSFER) VALUES
   (i.orderType             ,
    i.orderNumber           ,
    i.customerNumber        ,
    i.customerOrderReference,
    i.batchNumber           ,
    i.deliveryNoteNumber    ,
    i.elementNumber         ,
    i.orderLineNumber       ,
    i.creditNoteOrderNumber ,
    i.orderNumberCreditNote ,
    i.creditNoteNumber      ,
    i.creditNoteInvoiceNumber,
    i.invoiceNumber         ,
    i.itemClassification    ,
    i.itemMaterialNumber    ,
    i.invoicedQuantity      ,
    i.invoiceDate           ,
    sysdate);


  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
END;


begin
  DORTOSALES(l_xml);
end;
```

***FINAL UPDATE***

This is the one working

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "DORTOSALES" (P_DE_SALES CLOB)
AS
BEGIN
    FOR record_in_xml IN (
        SELECT xt.*
        FROM XMLTABLE('/dortoSalesInputIF/order'
            PASSING XMLTYPE(P_DE_SALES)
            COLUMNS
                ORTP VARCHAR2(6)    PATH 'orderType',
                ORNO VARCHAR2(20)   PATH 'orderNumber',
                CUNO VARCHAR2(20)   PATH 'customerNumber',
                CUOR VARCHAR2(40)   PATH 'customerOrderReference',
                BANO VARCHAR2(40)   PATH 'batchNumber',
                DLIX NUMBER(11)     PATH 'deliveryNoteNumber',
                ELNO VARCHAR2(16)   PATH 'elementNumber',
                PONR NUMBER(5)      PATH 'orderLineNumber',
                YREF VARCHAR2(60)   PATH 'creditNoteOrderNumber',
                OREF VARCHAR2(60)   PATH 'orderNumberCreditNote',
                CNNO VARCHAR2(20)   PATH 'creditNoteNumber',
                CNIV NUMBER(9)      PATH 'creditNoteInvoiceNumber',
                IVNO NUMBER(9)      PATH 'invoiceNumber',
                ITCL VARCHAR2(10)   PATH 'itemClassification',
                ITNO VARCHAR2(30)   PATH 'itemMaterialNumber',
                IVQT NUMBER(15)     PATH 'invoicedQuantity',
                IVDT NUMBER(8)      PATH 'invoiceDate'
        ) xt )
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO DE_SALES (ORTP,ORNO,CUNO,CUOR,BANO,DLIX,ELNO,PONR,YREF,OREF,CNNO,CNIV,IVNO,ITCL,ITNO,IVQT,IVDT,TRANSFER)
        VALUES (record_in_xml.ORTP,
            record_in_xml.ORNO,
            record_in_xml.CUNO,
            record_in_xml.CUOR,
            record_in_xml.BANO,
            record_in_xml.DLIX,
            record_in_xml.ELNO,
            record_in_xml.PONR,
            record_in_xml.YREF,
            record_in_xml.OREF,
            record_in_xml.CNNO,
            record_in_xml.CNIV,
            record_in_xml.IVNO,
            record_in_xml.ITCL,
            record_in_xml.ITNO,
            record_in_xml.IVQT,
            record_in_xml.IVDT,
            SYSDATE);
    END LOOP;
    COMMIT;        
END;

SELECT * FROM DE_SALES;
DELETE FROM DE_SALES;

begin 
dortosales('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<dortoSalesInputIF>
    <order>
        <orderType>DO1</orderType>
        <orderNumber>1304315</orderNumber>
        <customerNumber>5104081</customerNumber>
        <customerOrderReference></customerOrderReference>
        <batchNumber></batchNumber>
        <deliveryNoteNumber>8337697</deliveryNoteNumber>
        <elementNumber></elementNumber>
        <orderLineNumber>2</orderLineNumber>
        <creditNoteOrderNumber>617</creditNoteOrderNumber>
        <orderNumberCreditNote>59237</orderNumberCreditNote>
        <creditNoteNumber></creditNoteNumber>
        <creditNoteInvoiceNumber></creditNoteInvoiceNumber>
        <invoiceNumber>31615915</invoiceNumber>
        <itemClassification>TRA</itemClassification>
        <itemMaterialNumber>100000101</itemMaterialNumber>
        <invoicedQuantity>1</invoicedQuantity>
        <invoiceDate>20160531</invoiceDate>
    </order>
    <order>
        <orderType>DO1</orderType>
        <orderNumber>1304316</orderNumber>
        <customerNumber>5104082</customerNumber>
        <customerOrderReference></customerOrderReference>
        <batchNumber></batchNumber>
        <deliveryNoteNumber>8337698</deliveryNoteNumber>
        <elementNumber></elementNumber>
        <orderLineNumber>2</orderLineNumber>
        <creditNoteOrderNumber>618</creditNoteOrderNumber>
        <orderNumberCreditNote>59238</orderNumberCreditNote>
        <creditNoteNumber></creditNoteNumber>
        <creditNoteInvoiceNumber></creditNoteInvoiceNumber>
        <invoiceNumber>31615916</invoiceNumber>
        <itemClassification>TRA</itemClassification>
        <itemMaterialNumber>100000101</itemMaterialNumber>
        <invoicedQuantity>1</invoicedQuantity>
        <invoiceDate>20160531</invoiceDate>
    </order>
</dortoSalesInputIF>');
end;
```

Comment: Don't use the deprecated EXTRACTVALUE (or, indeed, EXTRACT); instead, use XMLTABLE. If you supply some sample xml, we can help you further with that.

Comment: Can You add some sample xml?

Comment: I just gave a sample XML with two records that should be inserted

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did not know that EXTRACTVALUE was deprecated - I am pretty darn new to PL/SQL

Comment: Your sample XML - are those two separate documents? Because otherwise, it's not valid XML (no root node present)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for single dortoSalesInputIF node:

```
declare
  l_xml      xmltype := xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<dortoSalesInputIF>
    <order>
        <orderType>DO1</orderType>
        <orderNumber>1304315</orderNumber>
        <customerNumber>5104081</customerNumber>
        <customerOrderReference></customerOrderReference>
        <batchNumber></batchNumber>
        <deliveryNoteNumber>8337697</deliveryNoteNumber>
        <elementNumber></elementNumber>
        <orderLineNumber>2</orderLineNumber>
    </order>
    <creditNote>
        <creditNoteOrderNumber>617</creditNoteOrderNumber>
        <orderNumberCreditNote>59237</orderNumberCreditNote>
        <creditNoteNumber></creditNoteNumber>
        <creditNoteInvoiceNumber></creditNoteInvoiceNumber>
    </creditNote>
    <invoice>
        <invoiceNumber>31615915</invoiceNumber>
        <itemClassification>TRA</itemClassification>
        <itemMaterialNumber>100000101</itemMaterialNumber>
        <invoicedQuantity>1</invoicedQuantity>
        <invoiceDate>20160531</invoiceDate>
    </invoice>
</dortoSalesInputIF>'); 

procedure DORTOSALES (i_clob in xmltype)
AS
  I_ORTP     varchar2(6);
  I_ORNO     varchar2(20);
  I_IVNO     number(9);
  I_CUNO     varchar2(20);
  I_YREF     varchar2(60);
  I_OREF     varchar2(60);
  I_CUOR     varchar2(40);
  I_ITCL     varchar2(10);
  I_ITNO     varchar2(30);
  I_IVQT     number(15);
  I_BANO     varchar2(40);
  I_IVDT     number(8);
  I_DLIX     number(11);
  I_ELNO     varchar2(16);
  I_PONR     number(5);
  I_CNNO     varchar2(20);
  I_CNIV     number(9);
  I_TRANSFER timestamp(6);
begin

  for i in  
  (
    SELECT  xt.*
    FROM    XMLTABLE ('/dortoSalesInputIF'
            PASSING  l_xml
            COLUMNS
              orderType               PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/orderType',
              orderNumber             PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/orderNumber',
              customerNumber          PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/customerNumber',
              customerOrderReference  PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/customerOrderReference',
              batchNumber             PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/batchNumber',
              deliveryNoteNumber      PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/deliveryNoteNumber',
              elementNumber           PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/elementNumber',
              orderLineNumber         PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/order/orderLineNumber',
              creditNoteOrderNumber   PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/creditNote/creditNoteOrderNumber',
              orderNumberCreditNote   PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/creditNote/orderNumberCreditNote',
              creditNoteNumber        PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/creditNote/creditNoteNumber',
              creditNoteInvoiceNumber PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/creditNote/creditNoteInvoiceNumber',
              invoiceNumber           PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/invoice/invoiceNumber',
              itemClassification      PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/invoice/itemClassification',
              itemMaterialNumber      PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/invoice/itemMaterialNumber',
              invoicedQuantity        PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/invoice/invoicedQuantity',
              invoiceDate             PATH '/dortoSalesInputIF/invoice/invoiceDate'
            ) xt
  )
  loop
    INSERT INTO DE_SALES (ORTP,ORNO,CUNO,CUOR,BANO,DLIX,ELNO,PONR,YREF,OREF,CNNO,CNIV,IVNO,ITCL,ITNO,IVQT,IVDT,TRANSFER) VALUES
   (i.orderType             ,
    i.orderNumber           ,
    i.customerNumber        ,
    i.customerOrderReference,
    i.batchNumber           ,
    i.deliveryNoteNumber    ,
    i.elementNumber         ,
    i.orderLineNumber       ,
    i.creditNoteOrderNumber ,
    i.orderNumberCreditNote ,
    i.creditNoteNumber      ,
    i.creditNoteInvoiceNumber,
    i.invoiceNumber         ,
    i.itemClassification    ,
    i.itemMaterialNumber    ,
    i.invoicedQuantity      ,
    i.invoiceDate           ,
    sysdate);


  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
END;

begin
  DORTOSALES(l_xml);
end;
/
```

BUT:

If you put your xml betwen f.e:

```
<t>
<dortoSalesInputIF>
..
</dortoSalesInputIF>
<dortoSalesInputIF>
..
</dortoSalesInputIF>
<dortoSalesInputIF>
..
</dortoSalesInputIF>
</t>
```

this code will also works

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Just a few questions from my very novice self.  You have entered a large "declare" statement. Is this just to have an input for the first run through. In the future, the stored procedure will be called passing this information in, correct?  In the PROCEDURE AS statement, I had called all the variables as I_<something> to separate them from the real column names of the tables. You took this over, but I don't see you using these, are they even needed?  I actually want this procedure to be called by another application passing the XML, does l_xml have to be defined?

Comment: I also don't understand your comment about the xml between "f.e", but I do see you putting a base node in with <t></t>, so I gues I code do multiple records this way.

Comment: Your very welcome :)

declare is just for me. You don't need to do this, but in your procedure input parameter should be xmltype, not clob.

There is no need to declare variables l_ just for inserting them later. [SElect INTO l_ -> Insert l_] will be bit slower than [Insert into i. ] and for thousands of records you'll feel the diffrence. 

comment about xml: XML which You provide it's not valid for xml parser. It is required to "cover" your_xml in the main tag(f.e. <t></t>)

Feel free to mark my question as correct :)

Comment: From my code just cut the part from BEGIN to END, from Yours delete all l_ variables and paste BEGIN... END

Comment: Hi!!! Thank you very much!!! This in a slightly varied form, is the solution I got working, especially after I found that EXTRACTVALUE was pretty much deprecated. I wanted to vote for you, but Stack Overflow says I don't have enough reputation to do so. but thanks anyways!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that you should be able to update to add in the rest of your columns:

```
WITH your_xml AS (SELECT 1 id, XMLTYPE('<toplevel><dortoSalesInputIF>
    <order>
        <orderType>DO1</orderType>
        <orderNumber>1304315</orderNumber>
        <customerNumber>5104081</customerNumber>
        <customerOrderReference></customerOrderReference>
        <batchNumber></batchNumber>
        <deliveryNoteNumber>8337697</deliveryNoteNumber>
        <elementNumber></elementNumber>
        <orderLineNumber>2</orderLineNumber>
    </order>
    <creditNote>
        <creditNoteOrderNumber>617</creditNoteOrderNumber>
        <orderNumberCreditNote>59237</orderNumberCreditNote>
        <creditNoteNumber></creditNoteNumber>
        <creditNoteInvoiceNumber></creditNoteInvoiceNumber>
    </creditNote>
    <invoice>
        <invoiceNumber>31615915</invoiceNumber>
        <itemClassification>TRA</itemClassification>
        <itemMaterialNumber>100000101</itemMaterialNumber>
        <invoicedQuantity>1</invoicedQuantity>
        <invoiceDate>20160531</invoiceDate>
    </invoice>
</dortoSalesInputIF>
<dortoSalesInputIF>
    <order>
        <orderType>DO1</orderType>
        <orderNumber>1304316</orderNumber>
        <customerNumber>5104082</customerNumber>
        <customerOrderReference></customerOrderReference>
        <batchNumber></batchNumber>
        <deliveryNoteNumber>8337698</deliveryNoteNumber>
        <elementNumber></elementNumber>
        <orderLineNumber>2</orderLineNumber>
    </order>
    <creditNote>
        <creditNoteOrderNumber>618</creditNoteOrderNumber>
        <orderNumberCreditNote>59238</orderNumberCreditNote>
        <creditNoteNumber></creditNoteNumber>
        <creditNoteInvoiceNumber></creditNoteInvoiceNumber>
    </creditNote>
    <invoice>
        <invoiceNumber>31615916</invoiceNumber>
        <itemClassification>TRA</itemClassification>
        <itemMaterialNumber>100000101</itemMaterialNumber>
        <invoicedQuantity>1</invoicedQuantity>
        <invoiceDate>20160531</invoiceDate>
    </invoice>
</dortoSalesInputIF>
</toplevel>') xml_data FROM dual UNION ALL
              SELECT 2 id, XMLTYPE('<toplevel><dortoSalesInputIF>
    <order>
        <orderType>DO2</orderType>
        <orderNumber>1</orderNumber>
        <customerNumber>2</customerNumber>
        <customerOrderReference></customerOrderReference>
        <batchNumber></batchNumber>
        <deliveryNoteNumber>3</deliveryNoteNumber>
        <elementNumber></elementNumber>
        <orderLineNumber>42</orderLineNumber>
    </order>
    <creditNote>
        <creditNoteOrderNumber>5</creditNoteOrderNumber>
        <orderNumberCreditNote>6</orderNumberCreditNote>
        <creditNoteNumber></creditNoteNumber>
        <creditNoteInvoiceNumber></creditNoteInvoiceNumber>
    </creditNote>
    <invoice>
        <invoiceNumber>7</invoiceNumber>
        <itemClassification>A</itemClassification>
        <itemMaterialNumber>8</itemMaterialNumber>
        <invoicedQuantity>9</invoicedQuantity>
        <invoiceDate>10</invoiceDate>
    </invoice>
</dortoSalesInputIF>
<dortoSalesInputIF>
    <order>
        <orderType>DO1</orderType>
        <orderNumber>11</orderNumber>
        <customerNumber>12</customerNumber>
        <customerOrderReference></customerOrderReference>
        <batchNumber></batchNumber>
        <deliveryNoteNumber>13</deliveryNoteNumber>
        <elementNumber></elementNumber>
        <orderLineNumber>14</orderLineNumber>
    </order>
    <creditNote>
        <creditNoteOrderNumber>15</creditNoteOrderNumber>
        <orderNumberCreditNote>16</orderNumberCreditNote>
        <creditNoteNumber></creditNoteNumber>
        <creditNoteInvoiceNumber></creditNoteInvoiceNumber>
    </creditNote>
    <invoice>
        <invoiceNumber>17</invoiceNumber>
        <itemClassification>TRA</itemClassification>
        <itemMaterialNumber>18</itemMaterialNumber>
        <invoicedQuantity>19</invoicedQuantity>
        <invoiceDate>20</invoiceDate>
    </invoice>
</dortoSalesInputIF>
</toplevel>') xml_data FROM dual)
SELECT *
FROM   your_xml yx
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE('/toplevel/dortoSalesInputIF' PASSING yx.xml_data
                           COLUMNS order_type VARCHAR2(5) PATH 'order/orderType',
                                   order_number NUMBER PATH 'order/orderNumber');
```

This works with XML documents that contain a single "dortoSalesInputIF" node as well as multiple like I've shown you. I've also passed in two XML documents in one go, assuming that your XML is stored in a table (you would replace references to "your_xml" with your table name, if that's the case).

Otherwise, if the XML is passed in as a parameter, you can simply pass the parameter directly in the XMLTABLE - i.e., you wouldn't need to join, just do:

```
select * from xmltable(... passing your_xml_parameter columns ...)
```

Once you have your select statement, you can then use that in an insert statement, e.g.:

```
insert into your_table (col1, col2, ....)
select col1, col2, ...
from   .....
```

This will be faster than your procedural "fetch a row, pull the data into variables, insert a row into a table", since the database does all the heavy lifting with no context switches between SQL and PL/SQL, and no passing data around.

Adding the insert into PL/SQL is easy; you simply plonk it inside the begin/end, like so:

```
create or replace procedure your_procedure (in_xml xmltype)
is
begin
  insert into your_table (col1, col2, ....)
  select col1, col2, ...
  from   xmltable(... passing in_xml
                  columns ...);
end;
/
```

(You wouldn't need the `create or replace` or `/` if this is a procedure inside a package.)

Comment: The idea is for an external application with the XML as a CLOB to pass it to the stored procedure. So what are the steps here? The calling application needs to run the stored procedure, but I do not see a "stored procedure" in your example. I am probably just missing something very basic in my understanding.  You way seems easier to follow, but I don't get how it works. Select * from xmltable and then inset in DE_SALES () select … FROM xmltable?  Can you explain, I don't get it.  As I said, I am very much the novice here.

Comment: So you need a procedure that contains an insert as select. I've given you the way to write the select statement; you simply need to amend the query for your purposes, add the insert section at the top and plonk the whole thing into your procedure. It should look something like `... procedure your_proc (in_xml xmltype) is begin insert into your_table (col1, col2, ...), select col1, col2, .... from xmltable(... passing in_xml columns ...); end your_proc;`